# Reverse for 'reports_views.views.patterns' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: django

I am suddenly getting a NoReverseMatch error in a production Django webapp. This code has not changed in months.  What could be causing this?

URL

```
urlpatterns = patterns('reports_views.views',
                       # report patterns plain urls
                       url(r'^patterns/$', 'patterns'),
                       url(r'^patterns/create/(?P<alias>[a-z_]+)$', 'create_report_pattern'),
                       url(r'^patterns/edit/(?P<pattern_id>[0-9]+|)$', 'edit_report_pattern'),
```

TEMPLATE
acc_base.html

```
<li id="bt_patterns">
    <a href="{% url 'reports_views.views.patterns' %}">
        <span class="icon icon-sitemap"></span>{% trans "Templates" %}
    </a>
</li>
```

TEMPLATE
reports_patterns.html

```
{% extends 'acc_base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load acctags %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block breadcrumb %}
    <div class="left">
        <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="/">{% trans "Home" %}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'reports_views.views.reports' %}">{% trans "Reports" %}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'reports_views.views.patterns' %}">{% trans "Report Templates" %}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

FUNCTION

```
@login_required
@access_focus
def patterns(request):
    data = dict()
    data['patterns'] = report_registry.get_available_reports()
    data['data'] = request.db_session.query(ReportPattern).order_by(ReportPattern.name)
    return render_to_response('reports_patterns.html', data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in docs for [`patterns`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urls/#patterns), the first argument is the prefix for your imported views, so I assume you have a view named `patterns` that lives in `report_views.views`. And as you can see in [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urls/#url) docs, there a optional param named `name`, used to call the url from a template with the `{% url %}` tag. You could try this:

```
...
url(r'^patterns/$', 'patterns', name='patterns_url'),
...
```

And the in your template:

```
<a href="{% url 'patterns_url' %}">
```